# How do I "get" a member variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, get, getter

```
function User() {
    this.firstname = null;

    get getFirst() {
        return this.firstname;
    }
}
```

> JavaScript console gives me an error saying "Unexpected Identifier" on line 12

```
var Jake = new User();
Jake.firstname = "Jake";
document.write(Jake.getFirst);
```

Comment: I have never seen that get keyword in javascript. Have you programmed in ActionScript?

Comment: This is an getter, you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get are you sure these getter are implemented in the environment you are trying to use them?

Comment: @osnapitzkindle: JavaScript's had a working `get` keyword since 2009.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used it. By the way, since we are talking about "Java"Script maybe Java coding styles are better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just not the syntax you use to define a getter. You'd use it in an object *literal*, like this:

```
var foo = {
    get bar() {
        return 42;
    }
};

foo.bar; // 42
```

...but that's not where your `get` is.

To define it where your `get` is, you'd use `defineProperty`:

```
function User() {
    this.firstname = null;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "first", {
        get: function() {
            return this.firstname;
        }
    });
}
```

Note I called it `first`, not `getFirst`, because it's an accessor function, which looks like a direct property access, and so is traditionally not given a name in a verb form:

```
var u = new User();
u.firstname = "Paul";
u.first; // "Paul"
```

If you wanted to create a function called `getFirst`, just get rid of the `get` keyword:

```
this.getFirst = function() {
    return firstname;
};
// ...
var u = new User();
u.firstname = "Paul";
u.getFirst(); // "Paul"
```

Comment: Within `Object.defineProperty(`…`)` you can write `get` instead of `value` and it would work as expected. It will still return `null` with this code, though, because the `firstname` isn’t actually being set to `"Paul"`.

Comment: @Xufox: LOL, good point. And thanks for the `value`/`get` catch.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that you are using `get` with a function rather than the object literal as outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```
var User = {
   firstName: 'Darren',
   get getFirst() { return this.firstName; }
}

alert(User.getFirst);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecao51n0/

Answer (score 0):

`get` is intended to be called within an object, not a function constructor. If you want to declare `getFirst` as a function on `User`, then here's one way you could  do it:

```
function User() {
   this.firstname = null;
   this.getFirst = function() {
      return this.firstname;
   }
}
```

Then you would also need to call `getFirst` as a function:

```
var Jake = new User();

Jake.firstname = "Jake";

document.write(Jake.getFirst());
```

Comment: But this question is about how to make it work as a getter, not as a function.

Comment: A "getter" is just a function that returns a value.